# Creating application to run coded web performance test in vsts

Tags: performance-testing

I have created a coded web performance test. Now, I'm running the test from visual studio. I need to run it as a application or as a exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Web performance test (coded or not) are only available for MS test execution engine. The only solution I found is to invoke the test  through mstest.exe.

You can find more informations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243149.aspx)